# 74hc595 Cascading

Tags: bit-shift

I have a problem with the SPI protocol. I have two 74hc595 cascade register and are connected with 7 segment.

I have the following pattern for displaying the numbers:

```
static const uint8_t Pattern[] = {
    0b01000000, // 0
    0b11101001, // 1
    0b00100010, // 2
    0b10100000, // 3
    0b10001001, // 4
    0b10000100, // 5
    0b00000100, // 6
    0b11100001, // 7
    0b00000000, // 8
    0b10000000, // 9
    0b11101111}; // BLANK
```

but I can't execute the program; there is a shift in bits when I want to display the number 1 or 4 or 7.

I noticed that these three figure ends with bit 1 (the problem is):

```
0b1110100**1**, // 1
0b1000100**1**, // 4
0b1110000**1**, // 7
```

With other numbers (0,2,3,5,6,8,9) the program works well.

Here is my program:

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

//#define Chek_Bit(var,pos) ((var) & (1 << (pos)))
#define HC595_PORT   PORTC
#define HC595_DDR    DDRC
#define HC595_DS_POS PC7      //Data pin (DS) pin location 42
#define HC595_SH_CP_POS PC5      //Shift Clock (SH_CP) pin location 40
#define HC595_ST_CP_POS PC6      //Store Clock (ST_CP) pin location 41

static const uint8_t Pattern[] = {
    0b01000000, // 0
    0b11101001, // 1
    0b00100010, // 2
    0b10100000, // 3
    0b10001001, // 4
    0b10000100, // 5
    0b00000100, // 6
    0b11100001, // 7
    0b00000000, // 8
    0b10000000, // 9
    0b11101111}; // BLANK

void shiftInit()
{
   //Make the Data(DS), Shift clock (SH_CP), Store Clock (ST_CP) lines output
   HC595_DDR|=((1<<HC595_SH_CP_POS)|(1<<HC595_ST_CP_POS)|(1<<HC595_DS_POS));
}


#define HC595DataHigh() (HC595_PORT|=(1<<HC595_DS_POS))
#define HC595DataLow() (HC595_PORT&=(~(1<<HC595_DS_POS)))



void SendSpiData(char data)
{

    for(int8_t i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        HC595_PORT|=(1<<HC595_SH_CP_POS); //HIGH

        if(data & 0b10000000)

        { //MSB is 1 so output high
            HC595DataHigh();
        }
        else
        {
            //MSB is 0 so output high
            HC595DataLow();
        }

        HC595_PORT&=(~(1<<HC595_SH_CP_POS));//LOW
        data=data<<1;  

    }

}


int main(void)
{



   shiftInit(); 


  HC595_PORT&=(~(1<<HC595_SH_CP_POS));//LOW
  HC595_PORT&=(~(1<<HC595_ST_CP_POS));//LOW


   while(1)
   {  

   HC595_PORT|=(1<<HC595_ST_CP_POS);//HIGH


   SendSpiDataV2(Pattern[7]);   //Write the data to shift register
   SendSpiData(Pattern[0]);   //Write the data to shift register

   HC595_PORT&=(~(1<<HC595_ST_CP_POS));//LOW


   }
}
```

When I send 7 and 0 (11100001 01000000) I receive in two registers 74hc595 (11100000 01000001) so data is not the same. NB: bit in position 4 "111**0**0001" is ignored it's BP in 7 segment.

Where is the problem? I think the problem is in the test `if(data & 0b10000000)`.

Comment: i have make mistake in the code of program:

Comment: SendSpiDataV2(Pattern[7]);   //Write the data to shift register is wrong

Comment: SendSpiData(Pattern[7]);   //Write the data to shift register

Comment: ^ If you have additional material to add, please edit the question, and do not add it to the comments. Thanks.

Comment: If I read the datasheet right, the input to the HC595 should be changed during the clock's *low* period. Try inverting your clock so you output data while the clock is *low* and then set the clock to *high*.

Comment: i will change it and i will tell you if it's ok